# In CRM 2011, hiding picklist values to other users

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

[image: Values hidden for others][image: Values]Values visible to Owner

Hi I know how to hide the values in textbox as shown above,But no idea how to hide values similarly in the picklist.If anyone have any idea please guide me.

Comment: you could also consider setting field level security for the field

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to "Password hide" the text in a pick list. You do have a couple options though:

1. Hide the field completely using the CRM `setVisible` javascript method.  Set the code to run on the onload of the form.  A slightly more "secure" version of this is to initially mark it as invisible in the CRM Form Editor, then make it visible for the users that need it visible.
2. Create a new form that doesn't even contain the field for the users that don't need access.  This is the most "secure" method, but it requires the security to be role based, and it looks like you need it value based.

Comment: Just to emphasise on option 1) - the value will be sent to the client, and not displayed. This might have implications (which is what Daryl is saying) as a user could fairly easily see what is in that field by pressing F12 or right click -> View Source